# Why is uploadArchives not listed at the tasks list?

Tags: gradle

i thought uploadArchives is a task which is provided by the java plugin.
In my build.gradle i use the java plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

But if i invoke `gradle tasks` on command line, i can't see the uploadArchives task.

Even not with gradle `gradle tasks --all`

The uploadArchives task is listed in the gradle java plugin documentation
see http://www.gradle.org/java_plugin (table 11).

I use gradle version 1.0-milestone-6.

I can invoke `gradle uploadArchives` without error, but the task is not listed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The uploadArchives task is added as a Rule to your build script and not explicitly by name. In  the output of "gradle tasks" you should see this line:

```
Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.
```

This means, that for each configuration in your build file, an according uploadTask exist. The java plugin adds an configuration named archives to your build script. By adding the configuration "archives" to your build script explicitly by the java plugin, the uploadArchives task is added implicitly too.

There are scenarios, where gradle can't know what tasks need to be materialized by a rule.

E.g.

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: ping<ID>") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
        task(taskName) << {
            println "Pinging: " + (taskName - 'ping')
        }
    }
}
```

There is no way to figure out which ping tasks should be shown as they are just materialized when triggered from commandline via 'gradle pingServer1 pingServer2 pingServer3'

regards,
René

Comment: I know you're one of the gradle developers... So shouldn't these implicite tasks also be listed in the tasks list?

Comment: These tasks are applied by a rule. that's why they don't show up in the ordinary task list but at the bottom of the output. One reason for this is, that they are created on the fly just when they are called from command line or when referenced in the build script.

Comment: Another example of a Rule is "Pattern clean<TaskName>" introduced by the 'base' plugin. When you call cleanCompileJava gradle finds no task with that name, but it finds a rule that says that matches this pattern of a "clean" + name of existing task (compileJava). in the implementation of the rule the on the fly created task "cleanCompileJava" deletes the output of the 'compileJava' task. I think it does not make sense to pollute the task overview with all the clean task companions of every productive task.

Comment: I updated my answer with another example where explicit listing of tasks isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

The uploadArchives task is a part of the maven-plugin. You have to add:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Comment: I can invoke `gradle uploadArchives` without error and without maven plugin.

Comment: Strange; always thought it belonged to maven-plugin. You've declared the 'uploadArchives {}' -configuration as described in http://gradle.org/maven_plugin ?

Comment: No haven't declared it. The uploadArchives doesn't do anything in that case. Here is the output:
`
>gradle uploadArchives

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:classes UP-TO-DATE

:jar UP-TO-DATE

:uploadArchives

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
`

Comment: It seems that the uploadArchives task is not listed until you actually add an 'uploadArchives {}'. It least on milestone-4